# pander function inside sapply in r

Tags: r, r-markdown, apply, pander

How we use `pander()` function inside a `sapply()` to `knit` a table into HTML/ word?

Here is my code

```
Data <- data.frame(A = sample(1:2,10,replace = TRUE),
                   B = sample(1:3,10,replace = TRUE),
                   C = sample(1:5,10,replace = TRUE),
                   D = rnorm(10),
                   E = rnorm(10, 10, 3))

Var_Cat <- 1:3
Var_obsn <- 4:5

sapply(Var_obsn, function(i){
  sapply(Var_Cat, function(j){
    print(Data[,c(i,j)] |> names())
    Data[,c(j,i) ] |> 
      kruskal.test() |> pander() |> print()})})
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xRUI.png)

I need to use 'rmakdown' to export my table (many tables at once). So I utilised the 'pander' function within 'sapply'. However, my output is not in a tabular format, so come help me with this.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way using `purrr` instead of `sapply`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df <- expand.grid(Var_Cat, Var_obsn) |> 
  rename(Var_Cat = 1, Var_obsn = 2) |>
  purrr::transpose() |>
  map_depth(1, bind_rows) |>
  map(~ Data |> select(.x$Var_Cat, .x$Var_obsn))

list_names <- df |>
  map(colnames) |>
  map(~ stringr::str_c(.x, collapse = "_"))

df |>
  set_names(list_names) |>
  map(kruskal.test) |>
  imap(~ broom::tidy(.x) |>
    mutate(Var_obsn_Var_Cat = .y) |>
    relocate(Var_obsn_Var_Cat, .before = statistic)) |>
  bind_rows() |>
  kableExtra::kable() |>
  kableExtra::kable_styling(bootstrap_options = "striped") |>
  kableExtra::kable_minimal()
```

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, my objective is to export separate tables. And I forgot to `group_by()` using `Var_Cat`. Also, need to remove `method` column.